# Whose power were Peter's "future dreams" borrowed from?

Tags: heroes

Early on in *Heroes* Season 1, Peter is subconsciously absorbing other people's powers and using them, usually unintentionally. Starting around the episode "Homecoming", Peter starts having "dreams" that are vaguely prophetic. They represent the disaster that's going to happen at the end of the season, but not in a way that accurately reflects the real events.

Which other powered person did Peter get this power from? Was this a result of having Isaac's foretelling, and if so, why don't they ever manifest to Isaac as dreams?

(These episodes seem similar to the time Peter was pulled into Charles DeVeaux's memory, but Charles' power isn't foretelling, it's some form of mental manipulation, so I don't think that explains these prophetic dreams.)

Comment: Like you said, in the beginning Peter was using other people's powers subconsciously. Dreams are a very good example of a "subconscious" process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His mom Angela from the beginning: http://heroeswiki.com/Peter_Petrelli#Abilities_Mimicked

Comment: The episode [The Second Coming](http://heroeswiki.com/The_Second_Coming) makes Angela's precognitive dreaming power explicit.

Comment: Yeah, I should have remembered this; I'm rewatching from S1 and I've apparently blocked most of S3 from memory.